# github авторизация state Exceptions

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, auth

Startup:

```
        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "GitHub";
        })
        .AddCookie()
        .AddOAuth("GitHub", options =>
        {
            options.ClientId = Configuration["GitHub:ClientId"];
            options.ClientSecret = Configuration["GitHub:ClientSecret"];
            options.CallbackPath = new PathString("/api/Account/SignInGithub");

            options.AuthorizationEndpoint = "https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize";
            options.TokenEndpoint = "https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token";
            options.UserInformationEndpoint = "https://api.github.com/user";

            options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, "id");
            options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.Name, "name");
            options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("urn:github:login", "login");
            options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("urn:github:url", "html_url");
            options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("urn:github:avatar", "avatar_url");

            options.Events = new OAuthEvents
            {
                OnCreatingTicket = async context =>
                {
                    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, context.Options.UserInformationEndpoint);
                    request.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                    request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", context.AccessToken);

                    var response = await context.Backchannel.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead, context.HttpContext.RequestAborted);
                    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                    var user = JObject.Parse(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());

                    context.RunClaimActions(user);
                    return;
                }
            };
        });
```

Выбираю провайдер:

```
    [HttpGet("api/[controller]/Login/{provider?}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(string provider = "GitHub")
    {
        return Challenge(provider);
    }
```

Коллбек:

```
    [HttpGet("api/Account/SignInGithub")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> SignInGithub2(string code)
    {
        return Ok();
    }
```

Настройке в гите:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Как щас](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AnisQr_M8o7_iQUJm5kuQKUg8x3b)

[Исходник на всякий](https://github.com/MACTEPwar/shop/tree/master/Shop_api)

Вопросы:

1) Почему после того как подтвердил свой логин в гите не происходит редирект?
2) Пробуем получить колбек с постмена и видим ошибку касающуюся поля state, почему:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

3) В `startup.cs`  есть event `OnCreatingTicket` в нем `user` определяется верно. Как мне его записать в БД?

Comment: Никто ничего посоветовать не может?